# Suggest a Product for Sharepoint printing

Tags: .net, sharepoint, pdf, cross-browser, product

This question is asking about a .NET product ,which best suits the needs to print diffrent format documents in doucment library of SharePoint directly to printer.There is no such products.So we have to convert it into PDF and then merge and print.So please suggest a product,which allow us to do the following functionalities.

1. Convert Word,Excel,PowerPoint,Images,HTML,XML to PDF.
2. Having the capability to merge PDF documents into one PDF.
3. Functionality to send the PDF document directly to printer.
4. Have to work well,when integrated with SharePoint 2010,2007.
5. Cross browser .

Please suggest one product.Thanking You

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). It supports all the formats you are interested in and more. In addition to a SharePoint GUI it has full support for workflows and comes with watermarking, PDF Security and a friendly web services interface as well.

No support for printing yet, but that is planned for a future (free) upgrade.

Please note that this is a product I have worked on, so consider me biased. Having said that, it is a great product, actively developed, with many happy customers

Comment: i would like to use some free versions of libraries.Any idea of like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer)? It may not cover all of your requirements but might still be an alternative.

Comment: Hi Jimmy,Thats an Interesting choice.But it doesn't suit and satisfy all the functionality needed.Thank You